# Multi GPU training Keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning

Iam quite new to Keras and want to train my model on 4 Gpu's.
Unfortunately I get an out of memory error with a batch size of 4. (input shape 256x265x32).

Now Iam wondering if it is possible to train on all 4 GPUs though with a batch size of 2?

Thanks in advance,

Kind regards,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and it is quite easy to do with their multi_gpu API (https://keras.io/utils/#multi_gpu_model).

The following line should do the trick and automatically split your batch into sub batches and concatenate at the end:

```
keras.utils.multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=None, cpu_merge=True, cpu_relocation=False)
```

The only problem you will have is batchnormalization, which will not use the entire batch but only these small sub batches. Also batchnormalization does not work well for small batches (e.g. batch size < 8). So I would suggest to not use batch norm for such problems.